# What does (for the last day and a half) mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, time

> Lastly,I'd like to thank all of you for investing your time and your energy, and clearly your enthusiasm in this, participating in this workshop. For engaging in the dialogues that we've had **for the last day and a half**. And for your contributions to the discussion.

I came across this and wondered if it was a commonly-used idiom.

I'm not sure if it gives the sense of doing something enjoyable all day.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A day and a half" means a duration of one day plus half a day, and yes it is perfectly idiomatic to say that.

What constitutes a "day" can vary in different contexts. A day can mean 24 hours or just the daylight hours of that. It many cases, it refers to a person's *working day* - often around 8 hours with some kind of break in the middle to mark a morning and an afternoon. If somebody told me that they were "working for a day and a half" I would imagine that to mean they did a normal 8 hours of work one day, and 4 hours work the next (or until their midday break).

Comment: thank you, its clearer to me know , so this is more of a business-related expression , most example sentences that I've gone through were business-related as you've implied , but in the other ones , "for the last day" was used alone , in this case , what does that suggest ?

Comment: Yes. Those depending on the context, "I worked for a day and half" could mean "I worked for 8 hours one day and then for 4 hours the next day", or it could mean "I worked for 36 straight hours". It just depends.

Comment: thank you jay .